# Tensor characterization

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensors

I want to show that $T^{1}_{1}(V)$ is isomorphic to $End(V)$. I know how to produce a linear map from $h:End(V)$ to $T^{1}_{1}(V)$, i.e. send $f \in End(V)$ to $hf(w,v) = w(f(v))$, but how to write down its inverse explicitly since I want to calculate the trace of its inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any vector space $X$, write "$X^T$" for its dual.

Then we define $g:T^1_1(V)\to \mathrm{Hom}(V,V^{TT})$ by $((gb)v)w = b(w,v)$.

When $V$ is finite dimensional we have $V^{TT}\cong V$, and then $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V^{TT})\cong\mathrm{End}(V)$ and $g$ gives the inverse to $h$.

Comment: You've identified $(1,1)$-tensors with bilinear forms implicitly, but apart from that you way looks to me very neat and concise. Could you please explain how can you think of $(1,1)$-tensors as of $b(w,v)$, not using the isomorphism we are trying to prove?

Comment: @YuriVyatkin From the look of the question the questioner is *defining* $T^1_1(V)$ to be the set of bilinear maps $V^T\times V\to\mathbf{F}$ (this definition only agrees with the usual one in the finite dimensional case, but some GR and differential geometry textbooks use it to get to tensors quickly). This is how they can define $h$ by "$hf(w,v) = w(f(v))$". With your definition of the tensor product their definition of $h$ doesn't work, and indeed the $\mathrm{End}(V)\to T^1_1(V)$ direction become the difficult direction to do the construction.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, I am learning the tensor stuff from Lee's riemannian manifolds. He defines the ricci curvature in terms of the trace of curvature endomorphism. I am totally confused, since there are so many notations and identifications involved. It is really hard to compute its component functions.

Comment: How does the expression you give define an endomorphism on $V$?

Comment: @koch It didn't! I had a mistake in my answer, it should make sense now.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is that this fact holds only for finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$, so, in order to establish it, we are forced to deal with some kind of a "proof of dimensionality", e.g. a basis.

Notice, that elements of $T^1_1(V)$ are *finite* sums of "simple" tensors, that is, objects of the form $v \otimes \phi$ for some vector $v \in V$ and a "covector" $\phi \colon V \to k$ (a linear map) where $k$ is the base field, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Suppose, that $\{ e_i \}_{i=1,\dots,n}$ is a basis in $V$, where $n = \dim V$.

We have the dual basis $\{ \widehat{e}_j \}$ in $T_1 := V^* := Hom(V,k)$
and the elements in the dual basis are defined on $v = \sum_i v^i e_i$ by $ \widehat{e}_j (v) = v^j$.

Now, any element $t \in T^1_1(V)$ is uniquely represented as 
$$
t = \sum_{1 \leq j,k \leq n} a_{jk} e_j \otimes \widehat{e}_k \tag{*}
$$

(Think of a matrix $A =  (a_{ij})$ of the endomorphism that we a looking for!)

It is clear, that for $t$ as in $(*)$ we can assign an endomorphism 
$$
v = \sum_{i} v^i e_i \mapsto \sum_{1 \leq j,k \leq n} a_{jk} e_j \otimes \widehat{e}_k (v) = \sum_{1 \leq j,k \leq n} a_{jk} v^k e_j \tag{**}
$$

It remains to check that $(*) \to (**)$ indeed yields the inverse to your mapping.

I leave the verifications and final conclusions up to you. If I have time later, I will try to update this answer, and. in particular, improve the notation.